# How can I use Picasso to add icon to Marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, picasso

I would like to use Picasso to retrieve the Bitmap image to use as a marker icon but I am not sure how to do so. If I am using Picasso to insert an image into an image view, I know I can use:

```
 Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(URL).into(photo_imageview);
```

Of course this will not work if I pass it to `.icon()`

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks to anyone taking a look at this!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Picasso provides a generic [`Target`](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html) interface you can use to implement your own image destination.  Specifically, you will want to override `onBitmapLoaded` to populate your marker.

A basic implementation is given below.

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
    Marker mMarker;

    PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

You would use it like this --

```
marker = new PicassoMarker(myMarker);
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(URL).into(marker);
```

**Note** Picasso only holds a week reference to the `Target` passed to `into`.  Therefore, the `marker` reference needs to exist until the image is loaded to avoid have the callbacks being cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: Hey @iagreen It show only default android marker not the image, please help me out for this. And onBitmapLoaded method not called.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I would have to see your code to see what might be wrong. It is possible that the bitmap fails to load. The code above fails silently on failure.  You can add logging to `onBitmapFailed` and see if the bitmap is actually being loaded.

Comment: yes I log in onBitmapFailed but nothing display. And how can I show my code to you?

Comment: Open a new question.  Reference this question and say it isn't working.

Comment: @AnkitSharma See the edit, it sounds like it might be your problem. If you are loading from a url and you used my original code there was a good chance the callbacks would be cleaned up prior to network call completing.

Comment: somehow solved....that was my test app where I was trying to understand how it works, putting it into the app I'm actually developing make it work flawlessly

Comment: Awesome great solution

Comment: Awesome great solution Thanks!!

Comment: @iagreen , i used your code and its working fine but there is small issue. Can you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Check this google maps sample code, you can find a `InfoWindowAdapter` implementation to achieve it : 
[googlemaps/android-samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

As @iagreen answer for generating Icon from Bitmap, you can use ***Iconfactory***.

**Kotlin** Version:

```
class PicassoMarker(
val marker: Marker,
private val iconFactory: IconFactory) : Target {
override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
    Timber.d("picassoMarker onPrepareLoad : ")
}

override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
    Timber.e("picassoMarker onBitmapFailed: ")
}

override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
    try {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            marker.icon = iconFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Timber.e(ex, "Marker is dead")
    }
}

override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (other is PicassoMarker) {
        return marker == other
    }
    return false
}

override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return marker.hashCode()
}}
```

And use like this :

```
 fun addMarker(marker: Marker): com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker {
    val markerOption = MarkerOptions().position(marker.latLng)

    markerOption.icon =
        iconFactory
            .fromBitmap(
                Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    1,
                    1,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                )
            )

    val iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(context)

    val picassoMarker = PicassoMarker(
        mapProvider.map.addMarker(markerOption),
        iconFactory
    )

    try {
        val picasso = Picasso.get().apply {
            this.isLoggingEnabled = true
        }

        picasso.load(marker.iconUrl)
            .noPlaceholder()
            .into(picassoMarker)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Timber.e(ex, "Picasso crashed")
    }

    return picassoMarker.marker
}
```