# Android - setting marker icon after getting images using Picasso

Tags: android, google-maps

I am retrieving my images from a rest service using Picasso:

```
  void drawMarker (String imageName) {
        String imageLocation = "http://172.16.104.118//MyService/images/%s.png";
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(String.format(imageLocation,imageName))
                .into(imageView);

    }
```

I want to set the retrieved image as the marker icon but it's only accepting bitmap,

```
marker.icon("HERE");

                mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095469/how-can-i-use-picasso-to-add-icon-to-marker

Comment: thanks that helped me