# Custom google map marker icon is not working as expected. It shows both the loaded bitmap and the red pin

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, picasso

i Followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095469/how-can-i-use-picasso-to-add-icon-to-marker)

and here is my code

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    PicassoMarker picassoMarker = new PicassoMarker(marker);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(picassoMarker);


    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

and it works like a boss but issue is that its showing both the red pin and the loaded bitmap

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the marker twice. The first time you use Picasso to change the icon but the second time you are adding it with the default icon using your `MarkerOptions`. Just remove this line:

```
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: Ahhh my bad ...Thanks alot @antonio

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom marker icon like this

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_location));
```

If you are getting marker image from server then you should first download image in background thread using AsyncTask and then you can set bitmap to marker

Comment: thanks for bothering . Brother for your information you can ask picasso library to dowload it for your rather than using asych , thats what i did and  this made it much easier, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095469/how-can-i-use-picasso-to-add-icon-to-marker